# Unexpected token in bootstrap.min.js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I downloaded version 3.3.6, used their (Bootstrap's) sample file (see below) but get the error: uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected token {

. I added some hard returns to be sure which line was the potential problem:

```
html{font-family:sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}
```

Here's their file, with the links modified for my local file system:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="/programming/javascript/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="/programming/javascript/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Where in all of this is *bootstrap.min.js*"?

Comment: You're trying to load CSS as JS.

Comment: instead of `min.js` in `<script>` you have `min.css`

Comment: Totally right. My stupidity.

Answer (score 13):

This next to last line of your code is wrong:

This is how you reference a JS file.

```
<script src="/programming/javascript/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
```

if you want to reference this CSS file correctly, use this code:

```
<link href="/programming/javascript/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: It's amazing that someone else made the same exact oversight as me. I don't know how long it would have taken me to realize it if I hadn't found this question and answer on Google.